# Transient PDE with a complex boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a PDE, but one of the boundary conditions is complex, because it includes an integral over the function that I am looking for.

[image]

The code is shown below

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
R = 0.005;   (*cm*)
\[Rho] = 1.05;    (*g/cm^3*)
St = 57.14;   (*cm^2*)
W = 0.3;       (*g*)
V = 50;      (*cm^3*)
(*L was converted to cm^3*)
k = 0.035/1000;     (*mmol/cm^3*)
(*mmol/L was converted to mmol/cm^3*)
qm = 0.994;     (*mmol/g*)
C0 = 919.43*1000/(1000000*1000*112.4);       (*mmol/cm^3*)
(*200ppm was converted to 919.43mg/m^3 and then to mmol/cm^3*)
De = 3.5*10^-6;           (*cm^2/s*)

q = (qm*Cr[t, r])/(k + Cr[t, r]);
region = ImplicitRegion[True, {{r, 0, R}}];

if = NDSolveValue[{D[Cr[t, r], t] + \[Rho]*
  D[q, t] - De*D[Cr[t, r], r, r] == 
NeumannValue[0, r == 0], Cr[0, r] == 0, DirichletCondition[
Cr[t, r] == 
 C0 - Inactivate[
   NIntegrate[(St/V)*Derivative[Cr[t, R], r], {r, 0, R}]], 
r == R]}, Cr[t, r], {t, 0, 1000}, {r} \[Element] region, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}]
```

But it's giving me this error message:

```
NDSolveValue::dvnoarg: The function Cr appears with no arguments. >>
```

Comment: I'm __really__ not sure what you're trying to do with that `DirichletCondition`;  it doesn't seem to match up to anything in the equations above.  Can you add the equation in standard mathematical form rather than in code?

Comment: Also, do you mean `D[Cr[t, R], r]` rather than `Derivative[Cr[t, R], r]`?  I'm not sure that the second form actually means anything in `Mathematica`.  (But the former will evaluate to zero, so I'm still confused.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.